# Change content of button on waterfall display

Tags: buildbot

In buildbot's waterfall page, the buttons show the status of each build step. If the step runs, it simply shows 'Ran'. I want to edit this to give better info to the user. Where can I add this change from?

Comment: The answer depends on what version of buildbot you are running.

Comment: In that case you may care to *accept* my answer: [Here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Your question
then ceases to appear unanswered to SO users. You get some reputation points, and so do I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of buidlbot 8.12](https://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/v0.8.12/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#common-parameters), the keyword parameters of all buildsteps
include:-

> description
>
> This will be used to describe the command (on the Waterfall display) while the command is still running. It should be a single imperfect-tense verb, like compiling or testing. The preferred form is a list of short strings, which allows the HTML displays to create narrower columns by emitting a 
>  tag between each word. You may also provide a single string.
>
> descriptionDone
>
> This will be used to describe the command once it has finished. A simple noun like compile or tests should be used. Like description, this may either be a list of short strings or a single string.

In the python definitions of your buildsteps, you should set the `descriptionDone`
keyword parameter to an appropriate description for the completion of each buildstep.

Comment: I tried adding descriptionDone=["Completed"] to the buildstep, but it produced error.

Comment: You would need to post the code of a buildstep that produces the error,
and also the python backtrace of the error, to enable anyone to help further.